# Using OCUnit in Xcode for iPhone projects?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, ocunit

After configuring my iPhone app for unit testing, I belatedly noticed this warning in the documentation:

> iPhone OS Unit Testing Support: Unit
>   tests are not supported for iPhone
>   applications.

As some of the other Xcode documentation regarding unit testing is out of date...is this still the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCUnit unit testing seems to be available in 3.0 and later according to [this page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html)

That said, I use GHUnit and like it a good bit better (and it definitely supports iPhone). The GUI is great:

http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit